# Calculate RAM/CPU usage based on image size and pixel density

Tags: ios, swift, image, pdf

I have a PDF app that seems to be crashing when loading some documents into it, but not in a consistent manner.

This is the test code I was using to test if other things were causing the crash, but it happens in this too.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  let pdfFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "pdf")
  var body: some View {
    PDFViewUI(url: pdfFile!)
  }
}

struct PDFViewUI : UIViewRepresentable {
  var url: URL?
  init(url : URL) {
    self.url = url
  }
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    pdfView.setNeedsDisplay()
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.interpolationQuality = .none
    pdfView.pageShadowsEnabled = false
    if let url = url {
      pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    }
    return pdfView
  }
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

I've been looking into PDFs and see that some of the PDFs that are crashing are JPEG2000 images (`.jp2`), `2032x1356` pixels, and `2.8` megapixels. Other images are TIFF with similar raster and density.

Is there a way to calculate in Swift (or externally on command line) how much RAM a PDF would use based on a single page of the above - and then use it as a baseline multiplier?

The obvious way to fix the crash would be to re-process all the PDFs, but the way they're provided I'm not allowed to manipulate them in any way.

But if I can rename the `.pdf` to `.zip` and extract the images, find the largest raster size and density, I'd be able to calculate the max output and see if it would be outside the scope of the application.

---

#### Log file 1

Running with: `pdfView.setNeedsDisplay()` but none of the other options below it.

```
2021-12-10 14:16:31.144176+1100 testPDF[7780:932360] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-12-10 14:17:02.067162+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.067553+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.067580+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.067612+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.067635+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.068262+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.068286+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetShouldAntialias: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.068306+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetTextGreekingThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.068327+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidthThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.068347+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.071412+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.071473+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.071532+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFlush: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.132308+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.132549+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.132744+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.132832+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.132904+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.132976+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.133047+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetShouldAntialias: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.135412+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetTextGreekingThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.135501+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidthThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.135566+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.135629+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.135711+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.135869+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFlush: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.140990+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141111+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141148+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141197+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141231+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141761+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141831+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetShouldAntialias: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141898+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetTextGreekingThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.141997+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidthThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.142059+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.142215+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.142296+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.142379+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFlush: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143496+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143562+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143593+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143627+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143655+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143684+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.143978+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetShouldAntialias: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.144004+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetTextGreekingThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.144027+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidthThreshold: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.144049+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.144071+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.144100+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.144151+1100 testPDF[7780:932353] [Unknown process name] CGContextFlush: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2021-12-10 14:17:02.159860+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:17:02.194741+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.194859+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.194912+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.194963+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.195007+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.195080+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.195125+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.195166+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
2021-12-10 14:17:02.195207+1100 testPDF[7780:932349] [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1705600 bytes for bitmap data
(lldb)
```

#### Log file 2

Added in the environment tags from the logs

```
2021-12-10 14:20:17.565840+1100 testPDF[7784:933927] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-12-10 14:21:05.828833+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.830468+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.831330+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.832147+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.832967+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.833785+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.834666+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.835642+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.836499+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.837381+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.838254+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.839108+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.839970+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.840841+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.841769+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.842767+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.844455+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:21:05.852592+1100 testPDF[7784:933933] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason: 'Failed to grow buffer'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181cf1c9c 0x198ea5758 0x181dee9b4 0x181de760c 0x181c90868 0x181d14e94 0x181c804ec 0x183a40164 0x18368679c 0x183687b40 0x1836cebc0 0x183687a04 0x183b1fbb0 0x183b1faac 0x183b7dad8 0x183acdc98 0x183ad70d8 0x183a81434 0x183daa028 0x183ace068 0x183ad70d8 0x183a81434 0x183daa028 0x183ace068 0x183ad70d8 0x183a81434 0x183aeac88 0x183b13910 0x1c2144090 0x1c2144f44 0x1c2144d2c 0x1c2103b00 0x1c2103488 0x102e64718 0x102e65f94 0x102e6d150 0x102e6ddd4 0x102e794e8 0x1dbcbde84 0x1dbcbd9f0)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason: 'Failed to grow buffer'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

#### Log file 3

After adding in:

```swift
pdfView.setNeedsDisplay()
pdfView.autoScales = true
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
pdfView.interpolationQuality = .none
pdfView.pageShadowsEnabled = false
```

```
2021-12-10 14:32:32.889931+1100 testPDF[7839:939957] [Assert] -[UIScrollView _clampedZoomScale:allowRubberbanding:]: Must be called with non-zero scale
2021-12-10 14:32:32.890946+1100 testPDF[7839:939957] [Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
2021-12-10 14:32:33.032861+1100 testPDF[7839:939988] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-12-10 14:33:08.894022+1100 testPDF[7839:939981] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:33:09.360035+1100 testPDF[7839:939981] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:33:09.447526+1100 testPDF[7839:939981] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:33:09.451925+1100 testPDF[7839:939981] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:33:09.458566+1100 testPDF[7839:939981] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:33:09.462430+1100 testPDF[7839:939981] [Unknown process name] CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-10 14:33:09.476930+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <CGContextSetRGBFillColor+128>
   <<redacted>+348>
    <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
     <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
      <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
       <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
        <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
         <_pthread_wqthread+284>          <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477093+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <CGContextFillRect+52>
   <<redacted>+392>
    <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
     <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
      <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
       <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
        <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
         <_pthread_wqthread+284>          <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477163+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetCTM: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+424>
   <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
    <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
     <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
      <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
       <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
        <_pthread_wqthread+284>         <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477255+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+140>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477335+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+192>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477415+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+316>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477490+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetShouldAntialias: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+328>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477571+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetTextGreekingThreshold: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+352>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477652+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidthThreshold: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+384>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477741+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+416>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477820+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+448>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.477911+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+696>
   <<redacted>+100>
    <<redacted>+80>
     <<redacted>+636>
      <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
       <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
        <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
         <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
          <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
           <_pthread_wqthread+284>            <start_wqthread+8>
2021-12-10 14:33:09.478441+1100 testPDF[7839:939989] [Unknown process name] CGContextFlush: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+1360>
   <_dispatch_call_block_and_release+24>
    <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
     <_dispatch_lane_serial_drain+684>
      <_dispatch_lane_invoke+432>
       <_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread+852>
        <_pthread_wqthread+284>         <start_wqthread+8>
(lldb)
```

Comment: Why should we believe this is a memory issue if you won't provide the crash log or the real code that crashes?

Comment: thanks @KJ - interesting stuff and i get its not as straight forward!

Comment: @matt ill add them in now for you

Comment: "1705600 bytes" is not very much in the grand scheme of thing. I have to suggest that you may have already run out of memory before we reached this point. So the question then is, what are you doing that runs you out of memory? Instruments will answer that immediately.

Comment: @matt that's the odd thing - fresh boot of iPad, single app mode, auto launches into app. its not a device that has been on for days and many apps launched. iPad Pro M1 too